# Load a tag library for a template externally in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a template tag that includes a template:

```
def WidgeLoaderNode(IncludeNode):
    def __init__(tpl, scopes=None):
        self.scopes = scopes
                    self.tpl = tpl
        super(WidgeLoaderNode, self).__init__('""')

    def render(self, context):
                    self.template_name = self.tpl.resolve(context)
        scopes = self.scopes.resolve(context) if options else DEFAULT_SCOPES
        context.push()
        context['form'] = ScopeForm(scopes)
        fragment = super(WidgeLoaderNode, self).render(context)
        context.pop()
        return fragment

@register.tag
def widget_form(parser, token):
    bits = token.split_contents()
            tpl = parser.compile_filter(bits[1])
    scopes = parser.compile_filter(bits[2]) if len(bits) > 2 else None
    return WidgeLoaderNode(tpl, scopes)
```

The template has to be specified from the template. In those templates, I need to include a couple of tag libraries:

```
{% load widgets_tags helpers %}
```

. Is it possible to reduce boilerplate template code in them by loading those libraries from my node code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/342/ - i.e. django.template.add_to_builtins